# Rerunning spec x times if if fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, continuous-integration, cucumber, capybara

We have some feature specs which fails randomly. We don't have too much time to fix them and we don't really know for now how to do this. Because of that we must rerun builds on cicrcle ci until they are green. Is it possible to run some spec, and if it fails rerun this few times, until it's green?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to have a look at following gems:

https://github.com/dblock/rspec-rerun

https://github.com/y310/rspec-retry

(taken from discussion in https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/456)

Personally I think having flickering tests is worse then having no tests in the first place because the are adding hassle and they destroy the trust in tests in general, which you need for swift refactoring.

Best would be

1. delete them since they don't provide the value they should
2. take your time to rewrite them

For getting the time to do so try to convince management that the investment in time on fixing these issues saves a lot of developer time in the long run (best with quick example calculation: x fails a day, result in yyy extra minutes with devs waiting for the built to be green) ;)